# Strange association error with a has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**//////// UPDATE**

This is the output from the dev log when I submit the form as an update

> LogoCategory Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `logo_categories`.* FROM
>   `logo_categories` INNER JOIN `logos` ON `logo_categories`.`id` =
>   `logos`.`logo_category_id` INNER JOIN `logos_posts` ON `logos`.`id` =
>   `logos_posts`.`logo_id` WHERE `logos_posts`.`post_id` = 61

//////////////

If you had an app setup like below, does anyone have any idea why they would get an error like this... I can't find any info on it anywhere.

**ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughNestedAssociationsAreReadonly in PostsController#update**

> Cannot modify association 'Post#logo_categories' because it goes
>   through more than one other association.

*post.rb*

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :logos
has_many :logo_categories, :through => :logos
```

logo.rb

```
  belongs_to :logo_category
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
```

logo_category.rb

```
has_many :logos
has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
```

and my tables are...

> posts (id) , logos (id), logos_posts (id, logo_id, logo_category_id),
>   logo_categories (id)

I get the error when I try to save the post model's _form ONLY when I edit a post record and  I check or uncheck a logo_category checkbox.

Any ideas welcomed! Thanks

Comment: Can you describe the behavior you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a posts model that a user can assign any amount of logos (of which there are about 150). To avoid the form becoming an monster I want to split them into categories (which I have done). When a user clicks the checkbox for a logo_category it displays just the logos for that logo_category. That way the form remains manageable. My form updates the logos that are selected just fine, it just won't record logo_categories.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

post.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :logos
```

logo.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
```

**EDITED** :

Your 'logo_categories' migration looks like :

```
  create_table :logo_categories do |t|
    t.references :logo
    t.references :post
    t.timestamps
  end
```

Take a look on the link , it will help you to use HABTM:

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes

http://ramblings.gibberishcode.net/archives/rails-has-and-belongs-to-many-habtm-demystified/17

Comment: Also, make sure that the logos_posts join table actually references `posts_id`.

Comment: @Vik - both of my models already have those associations in them. I have added the dev. log output that I get when I submit the update

Comment: @ZekeTemplin the logos_posts table has the following columns (if thats what you mean?) id, logo_id, post_id, logo_category_id, created_at &  updated_at

Comment: @Vik Sorry, only just noticed the update to your answer. My migration doesn't look like that no. My logo_categories table only has id, name, created_at & updated_at